# expected type was 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point' but the actual type was 'GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, geojson, .net-6.0, nettopologysuite

When I uncomment this:

```
/*.Include(r => r.Establishment)*/
```

from this:

```
public bool ReIndexVeganItemEstablishments(
    VepoContext context
)
{
    _searchService.DeleteIndicies(SearchService.SearchIndexMappings[typeof(VeganItemEstablishmentSearchDto)]);
    _searchService.CreateIdx<VeganItemEstablishmentSearchDto>();

    var allVeganItemEstablishmentsArray = allVeganItemEstablishments.ToArray();
    if (allVeganItemEstablishmentsArray.Any())
    {
        var allItems = allVeganItemEstablishments/*.Include(r => r.Establishment)*/.ToArray();
        var searchResults = allItems.Select(item => {
            var toReturn = _mapper.Map<VeganItemEstablishmentSearchDto>(item);
            return toReturn;
        });
        _searchService.Index(searchResults.ToArray());
    }
    return true;
}
```

I get:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException An
> unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
> occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'An error occurred while
> reading a database value for property 'Establishment.Location'. The
> expected type was 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point' but the actual
> value was of type 'GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point'.'  Inner exceptions
> found, see $exception in variables window for more details.  Innermost
> exception      System.InvalidCastException : Can't cast database type
> public.geometry to Point    at
> Npgsql.Internal.TypeHandling.NpgsqlTypeHandler.ReadCustom[TAny](NpgsqlReadBuffer
> buf, Int32 len, Boolean async, FieldDescription fieldDescription)
> at
> Npgsql.Internal.TypeHandling.NpgsqlTypeHandler.Read[TAny](NpgsqlReadBuffer
> buf, Int32 len, FieldDescription fieldDescription)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)

The model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Establishment : CreatedBySomeone
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PlaceId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Suburb { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
        
        [Column(TypeName="geometry (point)")]
        public Point Location { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The db insertion code:

```
        if (entity.Establishment != null) {
            establishments.AddIfNotExists<Establishment>(
                entity.Establishment, 
                x => x.PlaceId == entity.Establishment.PlaceId);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            establishmentId = establishments.Single(a => a.PlaceId == entity.Establishment.PlaceId).Id;
            toReturnEstablishment.Id = (int)establishmentId;
        }

    public static EntityEntry<T> AddIfNotExists<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, T entity, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class
    {
        var exists = predicate != null ? dbSet.Any(predicate) : dbSet.Any();
        return exists ? null : dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
```

OnModelCreating:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Establishment>(establishment =>
    {
        establishment.HasIndex("PlaceId").IsUnique();
        establishment.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
        establishment.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
        establishment.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
        establishment.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
    });
```

Any idea why `Include(r => r.Establishment)` gets type `GeoJSON.Net.Geometry.Point`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have a configuration error.
Have a look at https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/nts.html

Comment: Yes thanks. I deleted GeoJson  and deleted `NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseGeoJson(); ` from startup.cs and added `NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseNetTopologySuite();` in its place, and viola, it works.

Answer (score 0):

use this:
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.UseNetTopologySuite();